# Want to read status 500 errors in .NET.  Fiddler shows me readable response, why can't I get in .NET?

Tags: .net, http, soap

In Fiddler, I can pass in a request and get a response 500.  Fine by me, I want my .NET code to handle this AND analyze the response message.  In the case below there is a meaningful message.  Yet using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse, I cannot get that information.

Here is the response from Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Sun, 25 Mar 2012 15:50:31 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1

010e
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>WSS header is missing from request. Can't do username token authentication.</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
0000
```

Here is my code which tries to catch the exception:

```
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse resp2 = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            WebException we = (WebException) ex;
            HttpWebResponse respp = (HttpWebResponse) we.Response;
            log.Info((int)respp.StatusCode);
            log.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
```

I just cannot get anything more from the exception object.  But I know the response should be readable.  Hopefully there are lower-level http classes I can use that I just don't know about now.  I don't want .NET protecting me from the real HTTP protocols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you've tried to do with `respp`. (I note that you're not using `resp2`, either.) For example, what does this do:

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
    using (HttpWebResponse respp = (HttpWebResponse) ex.Response)
    {
        log.Info((int)respp.StatusCode);
        log.Error(ex.ToString());
        log.Error(new StreamReader(respp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

(It's never been clear to me whether you *really* need to dispose of a `WebResponse` obtained in a `WebException`, but it's probably a good idea. You might want to dispose of the response stream as well, although I believe disposing of the response is good enough.)

Comment: when I post the request, it throws a 500 exception, so I am catching it here. With respp (I have a number of variations on "response" in the code, hence the funny name), I'm trying to read the response that is stored in the exception.  But maybe this is not even the right place to look.    Aha - I see the confusion - the "data" call is not even used.  I will remove that now.

Comment: @DanielWilliams: But you haven't said what happens when you *try* to use the response. My code tries to read the contents of the response - yours doesn't. What have you tried, and what was the result?

Comment: Aha, yes now I see.  I was just viewing the local variables in VS2010, did not try to read the response stream.  Lo and behold, that stream has the exact message I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can catch the [SoapException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapexception.aspx) instead.

```
try
  {
    // do your thing
  }
  catch (SoapException soapEx)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(soapEx.Code.ToString());
    //Load the Detail element of the SoapException object
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(soapEx.Detail.OuterXml);
    XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new
      XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    // Add the namespace to the NamespaceManager
    nsManager.AddNamespace("errorNS",
      "WSSoapException");
    XmlNode Node =
      doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("errorNS:Error",
                                           nsManager);
    string errorNumber =
      Node.SelectSingleNode("errorNS:ErrorNumber",
                                    nsManager).InnerText;
    string errorMessage =
    Node.SelectSingleNode("errorNS:ErrorMessage",
                                nsManager).InnerText;
    string errorSource =
    Node.SelectSingleNode("errorNS:ErrorSource",
                                nsManager).InnerText;
    MessageBox.Show("Error Number is " + errorNumber);
    MessageBox.Show("Error Message is " + errorMessage);
    MessageBox.Show("Error Source is " + errorSource);

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
```